# Django: fill form from get method

Tags: django, forms

Form:

```
class SearchJobForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField()  
    types = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=JobType.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

View

```
def jobs_page(request):
if 'query' in request.GET:
    form = SearchJobForm(request.GET)
else:
    form = SearchJobForm()
variables = RequestContext(request, {

                                     'form':form,
                                     })
return render_to_response('jobs_page.html', variables)
```

After i submit the form i try to get its values back in the form

```
 form = SearchJobForm(request.GET)
```

but it doesn't work(some fields dissapear). Maybe it's because of the ModelChoiceField. How do i fill the form with its values using get method?

Comment: There are only two fields in there, but you say that "some fields disappear". Which fields of the form do not get populated? How are you checking that the form object is being populated?

Comment: You might consider starting by submitting the form in a POST and change code to request.POST.  If that doesn't work then you can look elsewhere for the problem.

Comment: Only the submit button shows up - the other 2 fields dont show(the fields themselves). I cant use post because i have pagination and im not sure how to paginate with post.

Comment: Both `request.POST` and `request.GET` are [QueryDicts][1], so either should work. Are you sure that the request parameters are in the request.GET? If you `print request.GET` at the top of the views.py it does show the content in there?


  [1]: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects

Comment: yes i can see contents. For exmaple for ?query=d&types=1 i get  
QueryDict: {u'query': [u'd'], u'types': [u'1']} but the fields wont show up(

Comment: Please post the full code of your view.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you are trying to show a pre-populated form to a user. To do that, you need to pass the initial argument to your form:

```
SearchJobForm(initial=request.GET)
```

Comment: In Django 1.9.x worked only with `SearchJobForm(initial=request.GET.dict())`

Comment: @Jakobovski see my posted answer for accommodating list items.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, could you post your entire view method? I just tested it and doing

`form = SearchJobForm(request.GET)`

works fine. It has to be a problem at the surrounding code...

---

From your code I think you are expecting the form values to render back in HTML with the values populated... Is that how you are trying to check that the form object was populated? This won't work (and probably isn't what you want to do anyhow - you want to process the form values).

Try adding this to your view:

```
def jobs_page(request):
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchJobForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            print form.cleaned_data['query']
            print form.cleaned_data['types']
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = SearchJobForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
                                 'form':form,
                                 })
    return render_to_response('jobs_page.html', variables)
```

Check what gets printed out.

You really should go through [this trail](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) from the django docs.

Answer (score 1):

The currently submitted answers do not handle the scenario in which a list of values is passed as a GET parameter for a single key.  Under the hood, Django uses a [**MultiValueDict**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/datastructures.py#L43) data structure which doesn't have a good way of getting values from a key which has multiple values.  The code below compensates for that,

```
def get_initial(self):
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        initial = {}
        for key, value_list in self.request.GET.lists():
            if len(value_list) <= 1:
                initial[key] = value_list[0]
            else:
                initial[key] = value_list
        return initial
    return super().get_initial()
```

This code was written for class based views but could be easily adopted for use within functional based views.

Answer (score 0):

Form objects should descend from `django.forms.Form`:

```
from django import forms

class SearchJobForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField()
    types = forms.ModelChoiceField()
```

Comment: The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that. And see my comment to your question: what is not getting populated in the form and how are you checking that the data was populated?